# Finding the Darkest & Lightest Pixel with One Click in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there no way to find the color values for the darkest or lightest pixel of the image with one click? Programmatically, this is a basic level task, and compared to that manual workarounds to do this are relatively tedious.

Preferably, I'd like to use this by pressing down some extra key(s) on the keyboard, while clicking on the image with the eyedropper tool.

If this does not exist, and you would like this feature too, you may want to upvote it here:
http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/finding_the_darkest_lightest_pixel_with_one_click